# Publishing to Azure Service Bus Topic fails without error

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

**Update oct. 20, 2021**

It seems that publishing to a queue works as expected. When I publish to a queue, the message is persisted on the queue. Conversely, when I publish to a topic, the message is not persisted.

**Updated**

I have added a simple console app that reproduces the same behavior down below.

I am trying to send a message to a topic in service bus from an Azure Function. I have tried this with a managed identity using Mass Transit. I have also tried this with a shared access key using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus nuget package. Both methods complete without exception, but the message is not in the topic.

This is what I see when sending from my function:
[image: Azure Overview Metrics]

Additional settings on the topic:
[image: Topic Settings]

I am able to put messages on the topic using the Service Bus Explorer within the Azure portal.

There are no subscriptions on this topic. I did have one setup as a test earlier, but it has since been deleted.

**Mass Transit Setup (in Startup.cs)**

```
        private void ConfigureMassTransit(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) {
            const string KEY_QUEUE_SERVER  = "REDACTED";
            const string EMAIL_RETRY_TOPIC = "REDACTED";
            const string EMAIL_SENT_TOPIC  = "REDACTED";

            services.AddMassTransit(x => {
                x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) => {
                    cfg.Host(new Uri(config[KEY_QUEUE_SERVER]), host => {
                        host.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider();
                    });
                    cfg.Message<EmailSentEvent>(m => m.SetEntityName(EMAIL_SENT_TOPIC));
                    cfg.Message<TransactionEmailFailedEvent>(m => m.SetEntityName(EMAIL_RETRY_TOPIC));

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
        }
```

**MassTransitQueueAdapter.cs**

```
    public class MassTransitQueueAdapter : IQueueAdapter {
        #region attributes
        private readonly IBus _bus;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public MassTransitQueueAdapter(IBus bus) {
            _bus = bus;
        }
        #endregion

        #region methods
        public void PublishFailure(TransactionEmailFailedEvent failedEvent) {
            _bus.Publish(failedEvent);
        }

        public void PublishSuccess(EmailSentEvent sentEvent) {
            _bus.Publish(sentEvent);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**ServiceBusQueueAdapter.cs**

```
    public class ServiceBusQueueAdapter : IQueueAdapter {
        #region attributes
        private readonly QueueContext _context;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public ServiceBusQueueAdapter(QueueContext context) {
            _context = context;
        }
        #endregion

        #region methods
        private static ServiceBusClient BuildClient(string connectionString) => new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

        public void PublishFailure(TransactionEmailFailedEvent failedEvent) {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void PublishSuccess(EmailSentEvent sentEvent) {
            ServiceBusClient client = BuildClient(_context.SentTopicConnectionString);
            ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(_context.SentTopicName);

            Task.Run(() => sender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sentEvent))));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Simple Console App**

```
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            string           cs     = "Endpoint=sb://REDACTED.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=test_with_manage;SharedAccessKey=REDACTED;";
            ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(cs);
            ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender("test_1");

            sender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage("Hello World!"))
                  .Wait();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please define "message is never delivered to the topic" - how do you know it's never delivered?

Comment: @RomanPolunin There are no messages in the topic when I go to view them in the Service Bus Explorer.

Comment: I would check all TTL-related subscription settings, plus similar properties of the message set by the service bus explorer. E.g. message might be purged because there's no one listening on the subscription when you're posting. Also maybe see if your dead letter queue (if configured) is getting anything.

Comment: There is definitely nothing in the dead letter queue. Added addtional settings in the original post.

Comment: Could you try using Wait and block on the Task returned from the async call in PublishSuccess instead of running it on separate thread via Task.Run? I could imagine not awaiting the result could hide an exception from you. Not saying that Wait is a great solution but just as an experiment to rid of this possibility.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek I tried that. No exceptions were thrown and there are no messages in the topic (active or dead-lettered).

Comment: Increase verbosity for MSBuild output :

Visual Studio >Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions >
 Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity : Diagnostic
In your ServiceConfiguration add the line

 <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" va

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT your comment was truncated. I am not exactly sure what all you were trying to say there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with my understanding of topics in Azure Service Bus. I was expecting the Topic to act as a type of storage for messages. I was wrong in that assumption. The topic will only forward messages to subscriptions. The subscription can either persist the message or forward to another topic or queue.

With that knowledge in mind, I was able to get my Service Bus specific implementations working. I apparently still have a bit to learn about Mass Transit.

Comment: I am currently facing a similar issue. Do you mean here that a consumer of the Azure service bus must be set-up ? Only publishing a message to the service Bus via Masstransit without any application consuming it will not work ?

Comment: @aurel-LX you have to setup a subscription to move the message to another queue if you want to look at the message. I have gotten into the habit of creating a "dead end" queue to store messages. Because I am using a topic, I'll end up with another queue that my functions are watching, so this gives me a way to see what is sent.